# How to get Locations list in Google My Business API | PHP

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

How can I get locations list in Google My Business API. Where I retrieved account list but I can't figure out how to retrieve location.

Here is my code where I am getting accounts list

```
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX');

// Create Client Request to access Google API
$client = new Client();
$client->setApplicationName('my-app');
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri('https://example.com/callback');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage');
$client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
```

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

```
$service = new \Google_Service_MyBusinessAccountManagement($client);
$accounts = $service->accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts(); // get accounts
```

Answer (score 1):

To get google locations,
you can use this PHP [My Business file](https://github.com/spotonlive/php-google-my-business) to make things little easier.

First change you scope to `ttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage` then include the file and create a object of `Google_Service_MyBusiness` with you client and then do like this.

```
 $mybusinessService = new Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
 // Get the first account in the accounts array
    $accounts = $mybusinessService->accounts;
    $accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
    $account = $accountsList[0];


    // Get the first location in the locations array
    $locations = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations;
    $locationsList = $locations->listAccountsLocations($account->name)->getLocations();
    $location = $locationsList[0];
    var_export($location);
```

With this process you can also able to get google reviews.

For more details check this Google Business API [documentation](https://www.100utils.com/google-my-business-api-with-php-google-reviews-api/).

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help

"It's correct!!!

I increase this at my code:

```
$optParams = array(
'readMask' => 'name',
);

$list_accounts_response = $my_business_account->accounts_locations->listAccountsLocations("accounts/114893266195214446586", $optParams);
var_dump($list_accounts_response);
```

Thank you.."

source : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/2213#issuecomment-1042785983

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31918953)